# Merge sort step by step execution

Tags: java, event-handling, buttonclick

I am trying to execute merge sort step by step handled by an button click event. I am unable to perform this. What i want is when i click on a button called next, it executes a single step and so on. 
Core is my main class. which includes all the gui buttons etc.
here is my code. 
`

```
package sorter;

import sorter.Core;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import sorter.Core$step;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


// Referenced classes of package sorter:
//            Core

public class MergeSort_Step
    implements Runnable, ActionListener 
{
    private static List<Integer> lists;   
    private int counter =0;
    private int length_list;
    public static boolean STEP_BY_STEP=false;
    Thread sortingThread=null;
    public MergeSort_Step()
    {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Core.form, "Changes will apply on next sort");   
        Core.btnNext.addActionListener(new Core$step(this));


    }


private void clickperformed_1(ActionEvent evt) {

    STEP_BY_STEP = true;
    //sortingThread = new Thread (this);
    //sortingThread.resume();
    //run();
 }


static void access$click(MergeSort_Step x0, ActionEvent x1) {
    x0.clickperformed_1(x1);
 }
public void run()
{
    //*****************list
    length_list = Core.length;
    lists = new ArrayList<Integer>(length_list);
    for (int i = 0; i < length_list; i++) {
          lists.add(0);
        }
    //System.out.println("Results from file in list: " +lists.size());
    mergesort_list (0,length_list-1);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Comparisions : "+ counter, "Notification!", 1);
    Core.toggleSorting();
}


  //***************list
    public void mergesort_list(int low, int high)
    {
        sortingThread = new Thread (this);
        if(low < high)
        {
            int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
            mergesort_list(low, middle);
            mergesort_list(middle + 1, high);
            if (Core.STEP_BY_STEP == true || STEP_BY_STEP == true) 
            {
                merge_list(low, middle, high);
                //sortingThread.
                STEP_BY_STEP = false;
                Core.STEP_BY_STEP = false;
            }


    }
}



//***************list
private void merge_list(int low, int middle, int high)
{
    int i;
    for(i = low; i <= high; i++)
    {
        lists.set(i, Core.num.get(i)); //= (List<Integer>) Core.num.get(i);
        System.out.println("Current Array Status: " +lists.toString());
        Core.numStatus[i] = Core.DONE;
    }

    i = low;
    int j = middle + 1;
    int k = low;

    {
        while(i <= middle && j <= high) 
        {

            if( lists.get(i) <= lists.get(j))
            {
                Core.num.set(k, lists.get(i));
                Core.numStatus[i] = Core.DONE;
                Core.updateScreen();
                i++;
            } else
            {
                Core.num.set(k, lists.get(j));
                Core.numStatus[i] = Core.DONE;

                Core.updateScreen();
                j++;
            }
            k++;
            Core.numStatus[i] = Core.EVENT;
            Core.updateScreen();
            //Core.STEP_status = false;
            counter++;
        }
        while(i <= middle) 
        {
            Core.num.set(k, lists.get(i));
            Core.numStatus[i] = Core.EVENT;

            Core.updateScreen();

            k++;
            i++;
            Core.updateScreen();
            //Core.STEP_status = false;

        }

   }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


}`
```

I am very new to event handling and java gui implementation as well. any help will be appreciated.